# Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated - Selenium webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to select in a `<select>` html element an option but for some reason, I'm getting the following error:

```
Message: element not interactable: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated
(Session info: chrome=71.0.3578.98)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.42.591059 (a3d9684d10d61aa0c45f6723b327283be1ebaad8),platform=Mac OS X 10.14.2 x86_64)
```

The select `html` element:

```
<select id="test-id-1">
  <option value="">[Seleccione]</option>
  <option value="2019">2019</option>
  <option value="2018">2018</option>
  <option value="2017">2017</option>
</select>
```

And this is my source code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(URL)

Select(driver.find_element_by_id("test-id-1")).select_by_value('2017')
```

Thank in advice.

Comment: Please update your chrome driver.Chrome driver 2.42 supports up to chrome browser version 70 and you are using chrome browser version 71. You can download the latest chrome browser from following link : http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads. Please let me know if this help.If you still get the error after done that then let me know as well. Good Luck!

Comment: My guess is that SELECT is not actually visible (hence the error) but instead some other elements form a dropdown and that hidden SELECT holds the value.

Comment: Your guess @JeffC was excelent cause that was my real problem! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that `SELECT` is not actually visible (hence the error) but instead some other elements form a dropdown and that hidden `SELECT` holds the value.

Comment: you may add code source